# Is possible to combine two arrays? "array.join(array)"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I have two arrays:

```
var array1= [[1],[2],[3]];
var array2= [[10],[20],[30]];
```

is there a way to (have) a third array?

```
var array3 = [[1],[10],[2],[20],[3],[30]];
```

Maybe:

```
var test= array1.join(array2 + "<br>");
```

Comment: Question marks: 1 or 0, not an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the "concat" function

Join two arrays:

```
var hege = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var stale = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
var children = hege.concat(stale);
```

The values of the children array will be:

Cecilie,Lone,Emil,Tobias,Linus

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: no concat.... combine. In yuor case, i want "celie, emil, lone, tobias.

Comment: Note, if want to do a safe concat you'd do `hege.concat([stale])`

Comment: @elclanrs: That would give an undesirable result. `["Cecilie", "lone", ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"]]`

Comment: @cookiemonster: right... I was thinking of a different case. `concat` has some gotchas...

Comment: @cookiemonster infact....

Comment: @user3163117 Sorry, haven't payed enough attention to your question. Well, i never saw such a function that do what you want. But I believe that a single loop would do the job.

Comment: @user3163117: This answer will do exactly what your question describes.

Comment: i want ["Cecilie", "Emil", "Lone", "Tobias"]. No ["Cecile, "Lone", "Emil", "Tobias"] (with concate).

Comment: @user3163117: Oh, you want it zipped. Simple enough with a loop. Start writing some code.

Comment: @elclanrs Should I always use (or prefer to use) the mozilla developer network for references on answers?

Comment: @Foca: W3Schools has bad reputation in SO, for good reasons. I'd prefer to see MDN links, the info is just better, and the examples are more in-depth.

Comment: with loop is possible ? how please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `CONCAT` function like

```
array1 = array1.concat(array2)
```

OR, `APPLY()`

```
array1.push.apply(array1, array2)
```

Comment: not function, and it is not a "concat" the true way.... :/

Comment: You say so cause probably the order in which the items to be as in your posted code. Right? You can use a `for` loop and get the item combined but I am not sure about the order though.